# Format of numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

This is a pretty easy question, I was wondering how to decipher this array:

```
model[Best[i][j]][6]
```

Is it recreating another array based off of the 'Best' array within the brackets? I'm not sure how to translate this to myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about numpy arrays, this will return the value of array `model` positioned at `Best[i][j]` (this should be a number perhaps from another array) row and 6th column. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
model = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
Best  = np.array([[0,0],[1,1]])

i = 0   # Best[i][j] is 0
j = 1

print model[Best[i][j]][1] # It prints model[0][1], which is 2
```

Comment: Great. That's sorta what I thought it was, I was just looking for clarification. Thanks.